# Render Happening Before ComponentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am trying to load some initial data before rendering my components in ReactJs.
I am also using the `Flux` architecture for this process. Here is my `container`:

```
class MemoryApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        MemoryActions.getInit();
        this.state = {};

    }

    componentWillMount(){
        MemoryStore.on("init", () => {
            this.setState({
                memory: MemoryStore.getInit()
            });
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button">Get Random Memory</button>
                <h1>Memory App</h1>
                <MemoryImage memory={this.state.memory}/>
                <MemoryText memory={this.state.memory}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So in this file, I am calling the action `getInit()` which calls an API to fetch some data. Once this data is received, the `init` event will be emitted by the `store`:

```
class MemoryStore extends EventEmitter {

    getInit(){
        return this.memory_response;
    }

    initLoad(response){
        this.memory_response = response;
        this.emit("init");
    }

    handleActions(action){

        switch (action.type) {
            case MemoryConstants.GET_INIT_RESPONSE:{
                this.initLoad(action.response);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}

const memoryStore = new MemoryStore();
dispatcher.register(memoryStore.handleActions.bind(memoryStore));
export default memoryStore;
```

Then, as you can see, we set the state afterwards in the `componenWillMount()`. Then I want to render the components. One of the components is the `image`:
import React from 'react'

```
export default class MemoryImage extends React.Component{
    renderItems(){

        console.log(this.props); // ===> Here is my console.log
        if (this.props.memory){
            return this.props.memory[0].description;
        } else {
            return "Nothing";
        }
    }

    renderImage(){
        if (this.props.memory){
            return this.props.memory[0].image;
        } else {
            return "Nothing";
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{this.renderItems()}</p>
                <img style={{width:'200px'}} src={this.renderImage()} alt="none"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And after logging onto the console...

```
memory-image.js:10 {memory: undefined}
memory-image.js:10 {memory: Array(1)}
```

It appears to me that the components are rendered before I set the state in the `componentWillMount()` function. I do not want this, I only want the components to render after the the state has been set in the `componentWillMount()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is rendered, because right before the component mounts, you simply add en event listener:

```
MemoryStore.on("init", () => {
    this.setState({
        memory: MemoryStore.getInit()
    });
})
```

The function the returns (before the event), and renders.

The simplest solution (IMO) would be:

```
getMemoryItems() {
    if (this.state.memory) {
        return <div>
            <MemoryImage memory={this.state.memory}/>
            <MemoryText memory={this.state.memory}/>
        </div>
    }
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button">Get Random Memory</button>
            <h1>Memory App</h1>
            { this.getMemoryItems() }
        </div>
    );
}
```

or you could do:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button">Get Random Memory</button>
            <h1>Memory App</h1>
            { this.state.memory ? <MemoryImage memory={this.state.memory}/> : '' }
            { this.state.memory ? <MemoryText memory={this.state.memory}/> : '' }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are only registering an event handler in `componentWillMount`, which will be called when that event happens sometime in future (i.e. `init` in your case). `componentWillMount` will just register it and simply continue its flow (i.e. calling `render` function etc). Only when that event is fired, you will get `memory` state.

So if you don't want to render anything until `memory` state is available then you can simply put a condition in render like this

```
render(){
        if(!this.state.memory){
           // Just wait for the memory to be available
           return null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button">Get Random Memory</button>
                <h1>Memory App</h1>
                <MemoryImage memory={this.state.memory}/>
                <MemoryText memory={this.state.memory}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```